# Can we just use the uncertainty principle to explain something from nothing?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cosmology, spacetime, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, vacuum

I have been following the argument related to the early universe and the emergence of matter-energy from nothing.

They often refer to the notion of quantum fluctuations.

But I wonder if a simple explanation goes like this, instead:

***Since in the early universe, the scale factor in the Standard Model approaches to zero, we could say that the volume of spacetime, in the proper frame, is arbitrarily small and therefore the uncertainty of spacetime is close to zero. As a result, the uncertainty of momentum-energy must be arbitrarily big, close to infinity.***

So, one can conclude, simply using the uncertainty principle, that close to the big bang singularity, infinite momentum-energy is available in the early universe, which evolves first into radiation dominated and then matter dominated cosmos.

Is this argument correct?

My key question is about the origin of the super hot state, or infinite amount of energy, of the early universe, and **NOT related to the later stage**, i.e. formation of matter and anti-matter and leptogenesis.

Put it another way, are we talking about quantum fluctuations of the vacuum to basically mean an application of the uncertainty principle in a universe so compact that the uncertainty of spacetime is almost zero and hence the momentum-energy uncertainty is almost infinite?

Comment: Why there is something rather than nothing is a serious question that has not been answered yet. There are ideas. Here is a high level explanation of one of them. [Can leptogenesis explain why there's something instead of nothing?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PsqEcGMjEfo). Note that it takes considerably more than the uncertainty principle.

Comment: @mmesser314 appreciate your comment, but my key question is about the origin of the super hot state, or infinite amount of energy, of the early universe, the video you shared, is related to the later stage, about matter and anti-matter.

Comment: Don't you mean "space"  instead of "spacetime" in discussing volumes & uncertainties?

Comment: @D.Halsey because the question is about the very early universe, I would say spacetime...

Comment: If the universe is infinite, which seems to be a good possibility in view of the accelerating expansion, then it was always infinite and never had zero volume (even with a scale factor of zero).

Comment: "because the question is about the very early universe, I would say spacetime.." So how do you define the volume of spacetime and what are its units?

Comment: @D.Halsey So you say that even with a scale factor of almost zero, the uncertainty of spacetime is not close to zero?

Comment: No, I'm still not convinced about my original question.

Comment: @D.Halsey Let's simplify and say we only conisder uncertainty in time of the early universe in an infinite universe, shouldn't the zero time uncertainty result in infinite energy? That could be the answer to my question here.

Comment: @D.Halsey, Besides, I think in the "proper frame", even in an infinite universe, the volume of physical space is also zero for a scale factor of zero.

Comment: @VVM What do you mean by "uncertainty in time". Note that time is not an observable, so the Energy-time uncertainty principle is not the same thing as other uncertainty principles

Comment: @BioPhysicist Are you saying that there is no such thing as four-vector momentum and position uncertainty relation in relativistic quantum theory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe we can say your argument is correct because you are applying the regular quantum uncertainty principle in a domain which clearly calls for a quantum theory of gravity (which we currently lack).  We don't know to what extent the eventual quantum theory of gravity will leave the uncertainty principle unmodified.  Nevertheless, this is an interesting question to ponder.

Comment: I think this is more suitable for a comment, rather than an answer.

Comment: @ɪdɪətstrəʊlə comments are only to suggest edits or ask clarifying questions. This post is neither of those things

Comment: @BioPhysicist surely there are things in life that are neither edit suggestions/clarifying questions, nor answers to the question. What is their place in this site?

Comment: In particular, when, like in this case, they provide an interesting thought about the question, but do not answer it

Comment: @ɪdɪətstrəʊlə If it's not an edit nor an answer, then it shouldn't be posted at all. However, I don't see how this post isn't an answer.